# Fadeout the background when Bootstrap popover is open

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a few Bootstrap Popovers which open on hover. In order to add emphasis to the content on the popover, I am trying to fadeout the background when the reader hovers on the popover and remove the background fadeout when they click outside or move mouse cursor away from the popover.

So far, I have been able to get the overlay effect on hover, but it does not trigger the popover.

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".pop").hover(
          function(){$(".overlay").show();},
          function(){$(".overlay").hide();}
        );
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1200;
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a Plunker of what I have been able to achieve. -> http://plnkr.co/edit/orXRUXnVqiGvpeqlnplY?p=preview

The div with the overlay class is getting triggered but, seems very unstable. The overlay should get triggered but the popover must have a greater z-index and should be above it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it seems unstable, is because everytime the anchor is hovered, the overlay gets in the way and triggers the hover event again. To fix this, simply give the anchor a higher z-index than the overlay:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
.pop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

To make the overlay stay when the anchor data is hovered:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".popover", function() {
  $(".overlay").show();
});
$(document).on("mouseout", ".popover", function() {
  $(".overlay").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This partly solved my problem. But, the overlay needs to stay while the popover content is being hovered. I tried adding `$(".popover").hover();` to the JS and hide/show the overlay. But, that does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not working because the .popover div is added after the document has been loaded. To make it work, you have to make the function run even after the document has been loaded. I updated the answer with a way of doing that.

Comment: Have always wondered why document ready never worked on popovers. Had no clue it is loaded after the actual document load. Brilliant answer. Thanks! For anyone wanting the updated solution - http://plnkr.co/edit/orXRUXnVqiGvpeqlnplY?p=preview